# Why this selector doesn't work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I made a filter function if user enters any `text`, this function finds the rows in the table that has that `text`. This code is working but has a bug. That is, if someone wants to search for text 'edit' or 'delete' every rows are displayed because all the table row has 'Edit' and' Delete' button. So I want to use `Selector` to not search those buttons.

I tried `.filter`, `tr.can_filter` etc.. many selectors in `this3`. Ain't works ; (

```
// In real code, this1, 2, 3 written as 'this'. just for recognition. 
function filterItem(self){
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function(){
            var value = $(this1).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#myTable tr").filter(function() { 
            return $(this2).toggle($(this3).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
            });
        });
}
```

```html
// index.blade.php file
        <tbody id="myTable">
            @foreach($detail as $event)
            @php
            $datas = $event->participants->pluck('date', 'name');
            $array = JSON_decode($datas, true);
            $string = implode(":\n", array_keys($array))."\n".implode("\n", $array);
            @endphp
            <tr>
                <td class="can_filter">{{ $event->id }}</td>
                <td class="can_filter">{{ $event->your_name }}</td>
                <td class="can_filter">{{ $event->email }}</td>
                <td class="can_filter"><a href="{{ route('participants.create', $event->id) }}"
                    data-toggle="popover"
                    title="{{ print_r($array) }}
                    "> {{ $event->title }} </a></td>
                <td class="can_filter">{{ $event->location }}</td>
                <td class="can_filter">{{ $event->description }}</td>
                <td class="can_filter">{{ $event->date }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('events.edit', $event) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="{{ route('events.destroy', $event->id) }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="btn">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So what I expected is by `$("#myTable tr").filter(function() {` I'm filtering table rows, and this2 turns on/off each row. and this3 decides what to compare. I think it's comparing `this3=row == value` so I'm trying change this3 to .can_filter or add `return $(this).toggle($(this).has('.btn').length < 1 ? true : $(this).toggle(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);` so that I can except button from being searched. which is not working.

Comment: Even allowing for the odd reason you've used `this1`, `this2` and `this3` in the question, `return $(this).toggle(this)` makes no sense at all

Comment: 1. Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57865909/edit). 2. Click the `[<>]` snippet editor and post a RENDERED example. You do not have any Laravel or PHP related questions. It is all jQuery

Comment: Oh there was typo I edited it sorry for confusing! and in real code it's written as this! just wanted to separate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show whatever tr that has a cell with the typed content and ignore the edit and delete text:

Alternatively do not have any text in the cells  of delete and edit

```js
$("#myInput").on("input", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#myTable tr").hide();
  $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
  }).show()
});
```

```css
a.btn::after {
  content: "Edit"
}

button.btn::after {
  content: "Delete"
}

td { border-left: 1px solid black; padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<hr/>
<table>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>ID 1</td>
      <td>John "Delete" Johnson</td>
      <td>hotmail</td>
      <td><a href="" data-toggle="popover" title="title 1">Title 1</a></td>
      <td>Location 1</td>
      <td>Desc 2</td>
      <td>2019-09-10</td>
      <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="btn"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID 2</td>
      <td>Frank "The editor" Franklin</td>
      <td>gmail</td>
      <td><a href="" data-toggle="popover" title="title 1">Title 2</a></td>
      <td>Location 2</td>
      <td>Desc 2</td>
      <td>2019-09-11</td>
      <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="btn"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Old version looking ONLY at the cells that have class can_filter:

```js
$("#myInput").on("input", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#myTable tr").hide();
  $("#myTable tr td.can_filter").each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr")
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1 && $tr.not(":visible")) $tr.show()
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<table>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td class="can_filter">ID 1</td>
      <td class="can_filter">John "Delete" Johnson</td>
      <td class="can_filter">hotmail</td>
      <td class="can_filter"><a href="" data-toggle="popover" title="title 1">Title 1</a></td>
      <td class="can_filter">Location 1</td>
      <td class="can_filter">Desc 2</td>
      <td class="can_filter">2019-09-10</td>
      <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="btn">Delete</button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="can_filter">ID 2</td>
      <td class="can_filter">Frank "The editor" Franklin</td>
      <td class="can_filter">gmail</td>
      <td class="can_filter"><a href="" data-toggle="popover" title="title 1">Title 2</a></td>
      <td class="can_filter">Location 2</td>
      <td class="can_filter">Desc 2</td>
      <td class="can_filter">2019-09-11</td>
      <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="btn">Delete</button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Really thank you for your kind answer , but it's slightly different. If supposed that, `<td>Name 2</td>` is `<td>edit</td>`. and when user type 'edit', only 'ID 2 edit Email ... [Edit] [Delete]' row is displayed.

Comment: what a magic... thank you bro. I appreciate it. it's beyond of my coding skills though lol

Comment: `return $(this).toggle(($(this).has('.btn').length != 1) && ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1));` then what's wrong with this?! I thought this code means [there's no btn class and(&&) has typed value] => true.

Comment: I did not even want to start on that code. You are toggling AND testing the value. But you want to toggle the row depending on textual content of the row BUT avoid the text of the link and the button, then you cannot avoid looking at the cells. I will make another example where you can avoid it

Comment: See the first example which is not using the text of the buttons and links

Comment: Awesome. thanks I appreciate it! just one thing, what do I have to study(google) to understand your `a.btn::after {
  content: "Edit"
}

button.btn::after {
  content: "Delete"
}

td { border-left: 1px solid black; padding:5px}` code?

Comment: CSS pseudo selector content https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after